# How to handle push notifications with Cordova as they arrive and the app is closed

Tags: cordova, push-notification, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

Can I somehow detect push notification arrival and handle it using cordova when notification arrives and app is closed at that time? I am using cordova `com.clone.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin` but when notification arrives and app is closed then the event listeners registered by me using plugin javascript code are not 'alive' and I can't detect the arrival. Is it possible to achieve that in some other way using cordova?

Comment: Please mention the platform you are working on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are asking for iOS, then no. Your app cannot handle User notifications while in the background. If the user taps the notification banner, your app will open and you will get a callback with the notification payload which can be forwarded to JavaScript.

If you would like to process silent background notifications, that has to be done in native because JavaScript execution is suspended in the background AFAIK. You could implement a queue which just stores a background notification and then dispatches it to JavaScript when app returns to active state.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this solution, but did you try this:-

Add this in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method

```
NSString* jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"localStorage.NotificationId=%@;", dynamicNotificationId];
[self.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the official [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin).

In **Android**, a notification will be created in the status bar if the application is closed, otherwise the payload is passed to your application

Answer (score 0):

You can fire the on("notification") event when app is closed using the plugin phonegap-plugin-push > 1.6.2, and changing your backend response to :

```
{
   notification : {
      title : 'yourTitle',
      message : 'yourMessage'
   }
}
```

to

```
{
   data : {
      title : 'yourTitle',
      message : 'yourMessage',
      content-available : "1" //only for IOS

   }
}
```